Drag & Drop Constraints Konvajs
const handleDragMove = (e, shapeIndex) => {
  if (editing) {
    const updatedShapes = [...shapes]; //store all the shapes in an array to update the shapes
    const shape = updatedShapes[shapeIndex]; //update specific shape by it's index

      const newX = e.target.x(); //new x position for the shape (the target or destination)
      const newY = e.target.y();//new y position for the shape (the target or destination)

      // Ensure original points are stored
      if (!shape.originalPoints) {
        shape.originalPoints = [...shape.points || []]; //store the original points of the shape
      }

      // Calculate delta values
      const deltaX = newX - (shape.originalX || 0); //the difference between the old position and new position
      const deltaY = newY - (shape.originalY || 0);

      // Ensure shape.points is valid
      if (Array.isArray(shape.points) && shape.points.length % 2 === 0) {
        const updatedPoints = shape.points.map((point, i) => {
          const newPoint = i % 2 === 0 ? point + deltaX : point + deltaY;
          if (isNaN(newPoint)) {
            console.error(`Invalid point calculation at index ${i}:`, { point, deltaX, deltaY, newPoint });
          }
          return newPoint;
        });

        // Check for NaN in updatedPoints
        if (updatedPoints.some(isNaN)) {
          console.error('NaN detected in updatedPoints:', updatedPoints);
        }

        if (shape.type === 'polyline') {
          // Handle polyline dragging
          handlePolylineDrag(shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY, updatedPoints);

          const associatedDimension = findAssociatedDimension(shape, updatedShapes);
          const associatedCircle = findAssociatedCircle(shape, updatedShapes);
          if (!shape.originalX || !shape.originalY || !shape.originalPoints) {
            shape.originalX = shape.x;
            shape.originalY = shape.y;
            shape.originalPoints = [...shape.points || []];
            console.log(shape.originalPoints);
          }
           // Calculate and store the original dimension length and polyline length
           if (!shape.originalDimensionLength && associatedDimension) {
            const [dimX1, dimY1, dimX2, dimY2] = associatedDimension.points;
            shape.originalDimensionLength = Math.sqrt((dimX2 - dimX1) ** 2 + (dimY2 - dimY1) ** 2);
          }
          if (!shape.originalPolylineLength) {
            shape.originalPolylineLength = calculatePolylineLength(shape.originalPoints);
          }
            // Calculate the direction of the polyline
        const isHorizontal = Math.abs(shape.points[2] - shape.points[0]) > Math.abs(shape.points[3] - shape.points[1]);
          if (associatedDimension && associatedCircle) {
            console.log("associatedDimension && associatedCircle")
            const [dimX1, dimY1, dimX2, dimY2] = associatedDimension.points;
            const dimensionLength = Math.sqrt((dimX2 - dimX1) ** 2 + (dimY2 - dimY1) ** 2);
            const polylineLength = calculatePolylineLength(updatedPoints);
            const constrainedPoints = shape.points.map((point, i) => {
              const constrainedPoint = isHorizontal
                ? (i % 2 === 0
                  ? point + (newX - (shape.originalX || 0)) * (dimensionLength / polylineLength)
                  : point + deltaY)
                : (i % 2 !== 0
                  ? point + (newY - (shape.originalY || 0)) * (dimensionLength / polylineLength)
                  : point + deltaX);
  
              return constrainedPoint;
            });
            if (associatedCircle.originalX === undefined || associatedCircle.originalY === undefined) {
              associatedCircle.originalX = associatedCircle.x;
              associatedCircle.originalY = associatedCircle.y;
              console.log('Circle original position:', associatedCircle.originalX, associatedCircle.originalY);
            }
            updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: constrainedPoints };
            setShapes(updatedShapes);
            const intersections = findCirclePolylineIntersections(associatedCircle, {
              type: 'polyline',
              points: updatedPoints,
            });
            
            if (intersections.length > 0 ) {
              console.log("intersections")
              const [newCircleX, newCircleY] = intersections[0];
              const constrainedCircleX = Math.max(dimX1, Math.min(newCircleX, dimX2));
              const constrainedCircleY = Math.max(dimY1, Math.min(newCircleY, dimY2));

              updatedShapes.forEach((otherShape, index) => {
                if (otherShape.type === 'circle' && isSameCircle(otherShape, associatedCircle)) {
                  updatedShapes[index] = { ...otherShape, x: constrainedCircleX, y: constrainedCircleY };
                  setShapes(updatedShapes);
                  
                  
                }
              });
            }
            else {
              // Continue updating the circle even if there's no intersection
              console.log("no intersections")
              updatedShapes.forEach((otherShape, index) => {
              if (otherShape.type === 'circle'&& isSameCircle(otherShape, associatedCircle)){
              updatedShapes[index] = { ...otherShape, x: associatedCircle.originalX, y:  associatedCircle.originalY };
              setShapes(updatedShapes);
              }
              });
              const dimensionLength = shape.originalDimensionLength || 0;
              const polylineLength = shape.originalPolylineLength || 0;
                const constrainedPoints = shape.points.map((point, i) => {
                  const constrainedPoint = i % 2 === 0
                    ? point + (newX - (shape.originalX || 0)) * (dimensionLength / polylineLength)
                    : point + (newY - (shape.originalY || 0)) * (dimensionLength / polylineLength);
                  if (isNaN(constrainedPoint)) {
                    console.error(`Invalid constrained point calculation at index ${i}:`, { point, constrainedPoint });
                  }
                  return constrainedPoint;
                });
                updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: constrainedPoints };
                setShapes(updatedShapes);
        
            }  
         } else if (!associatedDimension && !associatedCircle) {
            console.log("!associatedDimension && !associatedCircle");
            //  Revert shape and circle if no dimension or circle found
            const dimensionLength = shape.originalDimensionLength || 0;
            const polylineLength = shape.originalPolylineLength || 0;
            console.log("dimensionLength",dimensionLength)
            console.log("polylineLength",polylineLength)
            const constrainedPoints = shape.points.map((point, i) => {
              const constrainedPoint = i % 2 === 0
                ? dimensionLength
                : point + (newY - (shape.originalY || 0)) * (dimensionLength / polylineLength);
              if (isNaN(constrainedPoint)) {
                console.error(`Invalid constrained point calculation at index ${i}:`, { point, constrainedPoint });
              }
              return constrainedPoint;
            });
            console.log("constrainedPoints",constrainedPoints)
            updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: constrainedPoints };
            setShapes(updatedShapes);
          
            updatedShapes.forEach((otherShape, index) => {
              if (otherShape.type === 'circle' && isSameCircle(otherShape, associatedCircle)) {
                updatedShapes[index] = { ...otherShape, x: otherShape.originalX, y: otherShape.originalY };
               
              }
            });
            setShapes(updatedShapes);
          }else if (associatedDimension && !associatedCircle) {
            const dimensionLength = shape.originalDimensionLength || 0;
            const polylineLength = shape.originalPolylineLength || 0;
            const isHorizontal = shape.points[1] === shape.points[3]; // Assuming the polyline has at least two points and is horizontal if the y-coordinates are the same
          
            const constrainedPoints = shape.points.map((point, i) => {
              if (isHorizontal) {
                // Handle horizontal polyline
                return i % 2 === 0
                  ? point// x-coordinates stay the same
                  : Math.min(
                      Math.max(point , polylineLength), 
                      dimensionLength
                    ); // y-coordinates constrained within the range
              } else {
                // Handle vertical polyline
                return i % 2 === 0
                  ? Math.min(
                    Math.max(point , polylineLength), 
                    dimensionLength
                  )
                  : point; // y-coordinates stay the same
              }
            });
          
            if (isNaN(constrainedPoints[0])) {
              console.error('Invalid constrained point calculation:', constrainedPoints);
            }
          
            updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: constrainedPoints };
          
            updatedShapes.forEach((otherShape, index) => {
              if (otherShape.type === 'circle' && isSameCircle(otherShape, associatedCircle)) {
                updatedShapes[index] = { ...otherShape, x: otherShape.originalX, y: otherShape.originalY };
              }
            });
          
            setShapes(updatedShapes);
          }
          
        } else if(shape.type=== 'circle'){
          // Handle dragging circle
          handleCircleDrag(shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY);
        }
        else if(shape.type=== 'dimension'){
         // Handle dragging dimension
        handleDimensionDrag(shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY);
        }
        setShapes(prevShapes => {
          if (areShapesEqual(prevShapes, updatedShapes)) {
            return prevShapes;
          }
          return updatedShapes;
        });
      } else {
        console.error("Invalid shape.points detected");
      }
    
  }
};
// Helper function to compare two arrays of shapes
function areShapesEqual(shapes1, shapes2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < shapes1.length; i++) {
    const shape1 = shapes1[i];
    const shape2 = shapes2[i];
    if (shape1.x !== shape2.x || shape1.y !== shape2.y || shape1.points !== shape2.points) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
const handleCircleDrag = (shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY) => {
  // Initialize original points only if shape has points
  if (Array.isArray(shape.points)) {
    shape.originalPoints = [...shape.points];
  } else {
    shape.originalPoints = []; // Default to empty array if points do not exist
  }

  // Update the circle's position
  updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, x: newX, y: newY };

  // Find and update the associated connector
  const associatedConnector = findAssociatedConnector(shape, updatedShapes);
  if (associatedConnector) {
    const updatedConnector = {
      ...associatedConnector,
      points: updateConnectorPoints(associatedConnector, newX, newY)
    };
    const connectorIndex = updatedShapes.findIndex(s => s.id === associatedConnector.id);
    updatedShapes[connectorIndex] = updatedConnector;
  }

  setShapes(updatedShapes);
};
const handleDimensionDrag = (shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY) => {
  // Update the dimension's position
  updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, x: newX, y: newY };
  
  // Update associated connectors if needed (assuming dimensions might have connectors)
  const associatedConnectors = findAssociatedConnectors(shape, updatedShapes);
  associatedConnectors.forEach(connector => {
    const updatedConnector = {
      ...connector,
      points: updateConnectorPoints(connector, newX, newY)
    };
    const connectorIndex = updatedShapes.findIndex(s => s.id === connector.id);
    updatedShapes[connectorIndex] = updatedConnector;
  });
  
  setShapes(updatedShapes);
};
const findAssociatedConnector = (circle, shapes) => {
  // Logic to find the connector associated with the circle
  // Example:
  return shapes.find(shape => shape.type === 'connector' && shape.connectedCircleId === circle.id);
};
const findAssociatedConnectors = (dimension, shapes) => {
  // Logic to find all connectors associated with the dimension
  // Example:
  return shapes.filter(shape => shape.type === 'connector' && shape.connectedDimensionId === dimension.id);
};
const updateConnectorPoints = (connector, newX, newY) => {
  // Update the connector points based on the new position of the circle or dimension
  return connector.points.map(point => point === connector.start ? [newX, newY] : point);
};
const handlePolylineDrag = (shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY, updatedPoints) => {
  const startX = shape.points[0];
  const startY = shape.points[1];
  const endX = updatedPoints[updatedPoints.length - 2];
  const endY = updatedPoints[updatedPoints.length - 1];

  // Constraints: Ensure polyline is within bounds
  if (Math.abs(endX - startX) > 100 || Math.abs(endY - startY) > 100) {
    // Revert to initial position if exceeds constraints
    updatedPoints = shape.points;
  }

  updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: updatedPoints };
  setShapes(updatedShapes);
  return;
};
// Helper function to find the associated dimension based on intersection coordinates
const findAssociatedDimension = (polyline, shapes) => {
  return shapes.find(shape => shape.type === 'dimension' && isIntersectingWithPolyline(shape, polyline));
};
// Helper function to find the associated circle based on intersection coordinates
const findAssociatedCircle = (polyline, shapes) => {
  return shapes.find(shape => shape.type === 'circle' && isIntersectingWithPolyline(shape, polyline));
};
// Helper function to check if a shape intersects with a polyline
const isIntersectingWithPolyline = (shape, polyline) => {
  if (shape.type === 'dimension') {
    const [x1, y1, x2, y2] = shape.points;
    return polyline.points.some((point, index) => {
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        return isPointOnSegment(point, polyline.points[index + 1], x1, y1, x2, y2);
      }
      return false;
    });
  } else if (shape.type === 'circle') {
    return findCirclePolylineIntersections(shape, polyline).length > 0;
  }
  return false;
};
// Helper function to determine if a point is on a line segment
const isPointOnSegment = (px, py, x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
  const dx = x2 - x1;
  const dy = y2 - y1;
  const dotProduct = ((px - x1) * dx + (py - y1) * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return dotProduct >= 0 && dotProduct <= 1;
};
// Helper function to check if two circles are the same based on their coordinates
const isSameCircle = (circle1, circle2) => {
  if(circle1 && circle2)
  return circle1.x === circle2.x && circle1.y === circle2.y;
else{
console.log("not the same");
return;}
};
// Helper function to calculate the length of a polyline
const calculatePolylineLength = (points) => {
  let length = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 2; i += 2) {
    const x1 = points[i];
    const y1 = points[i + 1];
    const x2 = points[i + 2];
    const y2 = points[i + 3];
    length += Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2);
  }
  return length;
};
const findCirclePolylineIntersections = (circle, polyline) => {
  const intersections = [];
  const { x: cx, y: cy, radius: r } = circle;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < polyline.points.length - 2; i += 2) {
    const x1 = polyline.points[i];
    const y1 = polyline.points[i + 1];
    const x2 = polyline.points[i + 2];
    const y2 = polyline.points[i + 3];
    
    // Calculate the distance between the line segment and the circle's center
    const dx = x2 - x1;
    const dy = y2 - y1;
    const a = dx * dx + dy * dy;
    const b = 2 * ((x1 - cx) * dx + (y1 - cy) * dy);
    const c = (x1 - cx) * (x1 - cx) + (y1 - cy) * (y1 - cy) - r * r;
    const det = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    
    if (det >= 0) {
      const t1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(det)) / (2 * a);
      const t2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(det)) / (2 * a);
      if (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 1) {
        intersections.push([x1 + t1 * dx, y1 + t1 * dy]);
      }
      if (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1) {
        intersections.push([x1 + t2 * dx, y1 + t2 * dy]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return intersections;
};
>! >             });
>! >             if (associatedCircle.originalX === undefined || associatedCircle.originalY === undefined) {
>! >               associatedCircle.originalX = associatedCircle.x;
>! >               associatedCircle.originalY = associatedCircle.y;
>! >               console.log('Circle original position:', associatedCircle.originalX, associatedCircle.originalY);
>! >             }
>! >             updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: constrainedPoints };
>! >             setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! >             const intersections = findCirclePolylineIntersections(associatedCircle, {
>! >               type: 'polyline',
>! >               points: updatedPoints,
>! >             });
>! >             
>! >             if (intersections.length > 0 ) {
>! >               const [newCircleX, newCircleY] = intersections[0];
>! >               const constrainedCircleX = Math.max(dimX1, Math.min(newCircleX, dimX2));
>! >               const constrainedCircleY = Math.max(dimY1, Math.min(newCircleY, dimY2));
>! > 
>! >               updatedShapes.forEach((otherShape, index) => {
>! >                 if (otherShape.type === 'circle' && isSameCircle(otherShape, associatedCircle)) {
>! >                   updatedShapes[index] = { ...otherShape, x: constrainedCircleX, y: constrainedCircleY };
>! >                   setShapes(updatedShapes);          
>! >                 }
>! >               });
>! >             }
>! >             else {
>! >               updatedShapes.forEach((otherShape, index) => {
>! >               if (otherShape.type === 'circle'&& isSameCircle(otherShape, associatedCircle)){
>! >               updatedShapes[index] = { ...otherShape, x: associatedCircle.originalX, y:  associatedCircle.originalY };
>! >               setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! >               }
>! >               });
>! >               const dimensionLength = shape.originalDimensionLength || 0;
>! >               const polylineLength = shape.originalPolylineLength || 0;
>! >                 const constrainedPoints = shape.points.map((point, i) => {
>! >                   const constrainedPoint = i % 2 === 0
>! >                     ? point + (newX - (shape.originalX || 0)) * (dimensionLength / polylineLength)
>! >                     : point + (newY - (shape.originalY || 0)) * (dimensionLength / polylineLength);
>! >                   if (isNaN(constrainedPoint)) {
>! >                     console.error(`Invalid constrained point calculation at index ${i}:`, { point, constrainedPoint });
>! >                   }
>! >                   return constrainedPoint;
>! >                 });
>! >                 updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: constrainedPoints };
>! >                 setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! >             }  
>! >          } else if (!associatedDimension && !associatedCircle) {
>! >             const dimensionLength = shape.originalDimensionLength || 0;
>! >             const polylineLength = shape.originalPolylineLength || 0;
>! >             const constrainedPoints = shape.points.map((point, i) => {
>! >               const constrainedPoint = i % 2 === 0
>! >                 ? dimensionLength
>! >                 : point + (newY - (shape.originalY || 0)) * (dimensionLength / polylineLength);
>! >               if (isNaN(constrainedPoint)) {
>! >                 console.error(`Invalid constrained point calculation at index ${i}:`, { point, constrainedPoint });
>! >               }
>! >               return constrainedPoint;
>! >             });
>! >             console.log("constrainedPoints",constrainedPoints)
>! >             updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: constrainedPoints };
>! >             setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! >             updatedShapes.forEach((otherShape, index) => {
>! >               if (otherShape.type === 'circle' && isSameCircle(otherShape, associatedCircle)) {
>! >                 updatedShapes[index] = { ...otherShape, x: otherShape.originalX, y: otherShape.originalY };
>! >               }
>! >             });
>! >             setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! >           }else if (associatedDimension && !associatedCircle) {
>! >             const dimensionLength = shape.originalDimensionLength || 0;
>! >             const polylineLength = shape.originalPolylineLength || 0;
>! >             const isHorizontal = shape.points[1] === shape.points[3]; 
>! >             const constrainedPoints = shape.points.map((point, i) => {
>! >               if (isHorizontal) {
>! >                 return i % 2 === 0
>! >                   ? point
>! >                   : Math.min(
>! >                       Math.max(point , polylineLength), 
>! >                       dimensionLength
>! >                     );
>! >               } else {
>! >                 return i % 2 === 0
>! >                   ? Math.min(
>! >                     Math.max(point , polylineLength), 
>! >                     dimensionLength
>! >                   )
>! >                   : point;
>! >               }
>! >             });
>! >             if (isNaN(constrainedPoints[0])) {
>! >               console.error('Invalid constrained point calculation:', constrainedPoints);
>! >             }
>! >             updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: constrainedPoints };
>! >             updatedShapes.forEach((otherShape, index) => {
>! >               if (otherShape.type === 'circle' && isSameCircle(otherShape, associatedCircle)) {
>! >                 updatedShapes[index] = { ...otherShape, x: otherShape.originalX, y: otherShape.originalY };
>! >               }
>! >             });
>! >             setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! >           }
>! >         } else if(shape.type=== 'circle'){
>! >           handleCircleDrag(shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY);
>! >         }
>! >         else if(shape.type=== 'dimension'){
>! >         handleDimensionDrag(shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY);
>! >         }
>! >         setShapes(prevShapes => {
>! >           if (areShapesEqual(prevShapes, updatedShapes)) {
>! >             return prevShapes;
>! >           }
>! >           return updatedShapes;
>! >         });
>! >       } else {
>! >         console.error("Invalid shape.points detected");
>! >       }
>! >   }
>! > };
>! > function areShapesEqual(shapes1, shapes2) {
>! >   for (let i = 0; i < shapes1.length; i++) {
>! >     const shape1 = shapes1[i];
>! >     const shape2 = shapes2[i];
>! >     if (shape1.x !== shape2.x || shape1.y !== shape2.y || shape1.points !== shape2.points) {
>! >       return false;
>! >     }
>! >   }
>! >   return true;
>! > }
>! > const handleCircleDrag = (shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY) => {
>! >   if (Array.isArray(shape.points)) {
>! >     shape.originalPoints = [...shape.points];
>! >   } else {
>! >     shape.originalPoints = [];  
>! >   }
>! >   updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, x: newX, y: newY };
>! >   const associatedConnector = findAssociatedConnector(shape, updatedShapes);
>! >   if (associatedConnector) {
>! >     const updatedConnector = {
>! >       ...associatedConnector,
>! >       points: updateConnectorPoints(associatedConnector, newX, newY)
>! >     };
>! >     const connectorIndex = updatedShapes.findIndex(s => s.id === associatedConnector.id);
>! >     updatedShapes[connectorIndex] = updatedConnector;
>! >   }
>! >   setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! > };
>! > const handleDimensionDrag = (shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY) => {
>! >   updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, x: newX, y: newY };
>! >   const associatedConnectors = findAssociatedConnectors(shape, updatedShapes);
>! >   associatedConnectors.forEach(connector => {
>! >     const updatedConnector = {
>! >       ...connector,
>! >       points: updateConnectorPoints(connector, newX, newY)
>! >     };
>! >     const connectorIndex = updatedShapes.findIndex(s => s.id === connector.id);
>! >     updatedShapes[connectorIndex] = updatedConnector;
>! >   }); 
>! >   setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! > };
>! > const findAssociatedConnector = (circle, shapes) => {
>! >   return shapes.find(shape => shape.type === 'connector' && shape.connectedCircleId === circle.id);
>! > };
>! > const findAssociatedConnectors = (dimension, shapes) => {
>! >   return shapes.filter(shape => shape.type === 'connector' && shape.connectedDimensionId === dimension.id);
>! > };
>! > const updateConnectorPoints = (connector, newX, newY) => {
>! >   return connector.points.map(point => point === connector.start ? [newX, newY] : point);
>! > };
>! > const handlePolylineDrag = (shapeIndex, shape, updatedShapes, newX, newY, updatedPoints) => {
>! >   const startX = shape.points[0];
>! >   const startY = shape.points[1];
>! >   const endX = updatedPoints[updatedPoints.length - 2];
>! >   const endY = updatedPoints[updatedPoints.length - 1];ds
>! >   if (Math.abs(endX - startX) > 100 || Math.abs(endY - startY) > 100) {
>! >     updatedPoints = shape.points;
>! >   }
>! >   updatedShapes[shapeIndex] = { ...shape, points: updatedPoints };
>! >   setShapes(updatedShapes);
>! >   return;
>! > };
>! > const findAssociatedDimension = (polyline, shapes) => {
>! >   return shapes.find(shape => shape.type === 'dimension' && isIntersectingWithPolyline(shape, polyline));
>! > };
>! > const findAssociatedCircle = (polyline, shapes) => {
>! >   return shapes.find(shape => shape.type === 'circle' && isIntersectingWithPolyline(shape, polyline));
>! > };
>! > const isIntersectingWithPolyline = (shape, polyline) => {
>! >   if (shape.type === 'dimension') {
>! >     const [x1, y1, x2, y2] = shape.points;
>! >     return polyline.points.some((point, index) => {
>! >       if (index % 2 === 0) {
>! >         return isPointOnSegment(point, polyline.points[index + 1], x1, y1, x2, y2);
>! >       }
>! >       return false;
>! >     });
>! >   } else if (shape.type === 'circle') {
>! >     return findCirclePolylineIntersections(shape, polyline).length > 0;
>! >   }
>! >   return false;
>! > };
>! > const isPointOnSegment = (px, py, x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
>! >   const dx = x2 - x1;
>! >   const dy = y2 - y1;
>! >   const dotProduct = ((px - x1) * dx + (py - y1) * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy);
>! >   return dotProduct >= 0 && dotProduct <= 1;
>! > };
>! > const isSameCircle = (circle1, circle2) => {
>! >   if(circle1 && circle2)
>! >   return circle1.x === circle2.x && circle1.y === circle2.y;
>! > else{
>! > console.log("not the same");
>! > return;}
>! > };
>! > const calculatePolylineLength = (points) => {
>! >   let length = 0;
>! >   for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 2; i += 2) {
>! >     const x1 = points[i];
>! >     const y1 = points[i + 1];
>! >     const x2 = points[i + 2];
>! >     const y2 = points[i + 3];
>! >     length += Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2);
>! >   }
>! >   return length;
>! > };
>! > const findCirclePolylineIntersections = (circle, polyline) => {
>! >   const intersections = [];
>! >   const { x: cx, y: cy, radius: r } = circle;
>! >   for (let i = 0; i < polyline.points.length - 2; i += 2) {
>! >     const x1 = polyline.points[i];
>! >     const y1 = polyline.points[i + 1];
>! >     const x2 = polyline.points[i + 2];
>! >     const y2 = polyline.points[i + 3];
>! >     
>! >     // Calculate the distance between the line segment and the circle's center
>! >     const dx = x2 - x1;
>! >     const dy = y2 - y1;
>! >     const a = dx * dx + dy * dy;
>! >     const b = 2 * ((x1 - cx) * dx + (y1 - cy) * dy);
>! >     const c = (x1 - cx) * (x1 - cx) + (y1 - cy) * (y1 - cy) - r * r;
>! >     const det = b * b - 4 * a * c;
>! >     
>! >     if (det >= 0) {
>! >       const t1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(det)) / (2 * a);
>! >       const t2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(det)) / (2 * a);
>! >       if (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 1) {
>! >         intersections.push([x1 + t1 * dx, y1 + t1 * dy]);
>! >       }
>! >       if (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1) {
>! >         intersections.push([x1 + t2 * dx, y1 + t2 * dy]);
>! >       }
>! >     }
>! >   }
>! >   return intersections;
>! > };
>! > 
>! > ```

i have 3 shapes polyline, dimesnion(range)& the circle(connector). each polyline is associated with a dimension & a circle when i want to drag the polyline i want it to be dragged and dropped with its circle synchronously into its dimension range,both the polyline and circle should not be out of this range,the issue is the circle do not move syncronously with the polyline

Sorry but this is very hard to understand, might I suggest you try formatting the code in a clearer way? Maybe split it up into different parts so it's easier to read.
